# How do I get a JS script to parse raw JSON from a file?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a really simple JSON data file with no kind of wrapping, e.g.:

`[{"name:","fakename"}, {"lang:", "javascript"}]`

I'm trying to use this data in a js script in the same directory. I'm reading in both files in the document `<head>`, like such:

```
<script id="myJSON" src="data.json"></script> 
<script src="myScript.js"></script>
```

and then the part I'm stuck on is how to get myScript to SEE that JSON data. In the script I can do:

```
d =  document.getElementById("myJSON"); 
console.log(d);
```

The script returns the DOM element "myJSON" but I don't know how to access its JSON contents. I figured it would be a property like 'text' or 'value' or 'innerHTML' but I don't see it anywhere. I've tried various combinations of the type attribute in the  tag but none of that makes any difference.

I know I could use an API like fetch but that's more complexity than I want.  My best idea so far is to edit the json file to put an identifier at the beginning of the json file, like `var myJSON = '[{"json"}]';` so then myScript would have a clear handle to `JSON.parse(myJSON)`. But that's an extra step in an automated process which I don't want (or think I need).

How do I get my JS to see this "anonymous" JSON?

Comment: `<script>` elements are for loading JavaScript. JSON is not JavaScript. Use `fetch`.

Comment: Thanks, fetch is probably the best solution.

Comment: fetch took literally 5 min to plug in, thanks @Quentin!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use fetch, you could use the server side code (PHP, ASP, etc) to write the text of the JSON into a hidden div in the page, and then you could use `getElementByID` to get the text, followed by `parse` to get an object that represents the JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

This was not that much extra code but it was kind of a pain to wrap my head around. I had to wrap everything in a `.then` clause of fetch, or of an async function which called fetch. Here's what my code ended up looking like.

```
 readJSONFile().then(jq => {
          for (i = 0; i < jq.length; ++i) {
                console.log( jq[i].myJSONKey )
          });
```

```
async function readJSONFile() {
    const response = await fetch('data.json');
    const jq = await response.json();
    return jq;
}
```